# Why relation "parallel" on the set of lines in a plane not transitive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

My book says relation "parallel" on the set of lines in the plane not transitive.
And the definition in the book given is :

> A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is transitive if whenever $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc$, that is if whenever $(a,b),\,(b,c)\in R$ then $(a,c)\in R$.

What I thought is that if $a\parallel b$ and $b \parallel c$ then $a \parallel c$. Therefore it is transitive.

Comment: Is it because it is possible that $a=c$?

Comment: A line is not parallel to itself.

Comment: @DavidMitra Why this is not taken into consideration that maybe lines $a,b,c$ are distinct? and $R=\{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\}$?

Comment: @turkeyhundt: I'm sorry but that condition is nowhere mentioned in the book.

Comment: Right, but you cannot assume $a<>c$, therefore you can't assume $a\parallel c$

Comment: Can you please post the source (the textbook you are reading) with the passage saying the relation to be not transitive?

Comment: @Godparticle: Page 28-Example 2.6, page 30- Example 2.9. 

http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/~mi10103/predavanja/_ds1/DS.pdf

Comment: It literally says there "since no line is parallel to itself".

Comment: I, and some others, beg to difer: paralellism in the plane is a transitive relation. **But** it may well depend on some given *definition*: if it includes that the lines have no common point then yes: no line is parallel to itself. Yet not always is that the definition, and even advanced books can use *other* definition which yield transitivity, e.g. http://tinyurl.com/oyq7dvw